# Jailbroken iPhone not able to debug

Tags: ios, debugging, jailbreak

I have a Jailbroken iPhone 5.1.1. I used this [tutorial](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile) to make it ready for development.

Now; when I debug my Xcode project with iPhone plugged in, it says first:

```
Build Succeeded.
```

Then, it uploads the project to my iPhone. (Everything goes ok up to that moment.)

However, after I see a blank page on the iPhone's screen for only a sec, the program closes itself and goes back to the normal home UI.

After that, If I run the program from my phone by clicking the uploaded program icon manually, it works great.

So, it works for uploading the application to iPhone, but not for debugging.

**Question:** Is there any way to make it work for debugging as well?

### EDIT:

I use Xcode 4.3.2.

**Console Errors after I run the application:**

1. Xcode: ERROR: Failed to create an alert for ID "enabled" based on defaults: 1
2. Xcode: AMDeviceStartHouseArrestService (thread 0x1066ba000): There was an error from the device: ApplicationLookupFailed

Comment: What is the version of xcode you are using? what is the error that gets printed in console?

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith: I'm editing the original post.

Comment: What was that '-1' for ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Jailcoder from http://oneiros.altervista.org/jailcoder/

It sets up xcode and your projects so you can run and debug on the device.

I had to re-install xcode the first time i used it as i had changed some settings myself and they conflicted,